# JS function change text on button click only works on Desktop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function set up so that when a button labeled "The Night" is clicked, dark mode is activated, and the buttons text changes to "The Day". This works fine in my Desktop navigation, but for some reason it doesn't work when put into my mobile navigation. You can view the site here to see what I mean: https://blanklandscape.com/

HTML

```
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="sidenav">
        <div id="nav" class='container'>
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-f'>The Forest</a>
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-o'>The Ocean</a>
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-s'>The Sky</a>
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-m'>The Mountain</a>
            <input type="button" value="The Night" id="dark-btn" class="dark-mode" onclick="myFunction(); change();" />
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-a'>About</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

<!-- Navigation Mobile -->
        <div id="mobilenav" class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-f'>The Forest</a>
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-o'>The Ocean</a>
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-s'>The Sky</a>
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-m'>The Mountain</a>
                <input type="button" value="The Night" id="dark-btn" class="dark-mode" onclick="myFunction(); change();" />
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-a'>About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
/* Day/Night Mode */

  function myFunction() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}

/* Day/Night Button Text */

  function change() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("dark-btn");
    if (elem.value=="The Night") elem.value = "The Day";
    else elem.value = "The Night";
}
```

Comment: IDs must be unique in the document. `getElementById()` will only ever select the first element with that ID in the document. Use a class and `.getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: Thanks Turnip. Much appreciated. Still very new to JS and code in general!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the id of each node should be unique as per the rules, So instead of giving both buttons id you can give them a common class and achieve the result.

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="sidenav">
        <div id="nav" class='container'>
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-f'>The Forest</a>
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-o'>The Ocean</a>
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-s'>The Sky</a>
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-m'>The Mountain</a>
            <input type="button" value="The Night" id="dark-btn-1" class="dark-mode dark-btn" onclick="myFunction(); change();" />
            <a class='menu-button' id='menu-a'>About</a>
        </div>
    </nav>

<!-- Navigation Mobile -->
        <div id="mobilenav" class="overlay">
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-f'>The Forest</a>
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-o'>The Ocean</a>
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-s'>The Sky</a>
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-m'>The Mountain</a>
                <input type="button" value="The Night" id="dark-btn-2" class="dark-mode dark-btn" onclick="myFunction(); change();" />
                <a class='mob-menu-button' id='mob-menu-a'>About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and in your js code

```js
/* Day/Night Button Text */

  function change() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".dark-btn");
    elems.forEach(elem => {
        if (elem.value=="The Night") elem.value = "The Day";
        else elem.value = "The Night";
    })

}
```

or if you don't care about the rules and still want to have both of them same id. you can still get the expected behavior by this js code

```js
function change() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#dark-btn");
    elems.forEach(elem => {
        if (elem.value=="The Night") elem.value = "The Day";
        else elem.value = "The Night";
    })

}
```

Comment: Glad I could help, keep it up.